# How to obtain a Bing API AppID

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, bing-api, azure-marketplace

My intention is to access the Bing API in Windows Phone projects, where i have to  supply  APP ID in the code. Many tutorials have said the same story to access the APP ID like [Nokia Tutorial](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Text_to_Speech_in_Windows_Phone_7) and  [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/259727/Text-to-speech-in-windows-phone7) too. But Bing announces that now everything is shifted to Azure MarketPlace. I searched everthing and registered in Azure Marketplace. But there is no mention of APP ID. Can anyone help me how to get APP ID?

Answer (score 9):

The migration guide <strike>[here](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/developer/archive/2012/05/17/bing-developer-update-2.aspx)</strike> includes samples that no longer require AppIds but instead use Account Keys which are provided to you when you sign up to the Azure Marketplace. The migration guide should include everything you need to get started.

Comment: the link is broken :(

Answer (score -1):

You can get the Bing API here - http://www.bing.com/toolbox/bingdeveloper/

Comment: This URL now redirects to "http://www.bing.com/developers/".  There are no obvious instructions as to how to generate an AppID from the new location.